# How to group the elements of a HashMap by key and sum the values?

Tags: java, spring-boot, group-by, hashmap, sum

[image: Illustrative image of what I currently have in the HashMap.]

Hello, I would like to please group the HashMap items by nature and then sum the amounts for the repeating items.
I have to save the HashMap elements in the PartDonNature model.

```
public class PartNatureDon extends BaseEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "nature_don_col_id", nullable = false)
    private NatureDon natureDon;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "assistance_col_id", nullable = false)
    private Assistance assistance;

    @Column
    private double montant;
}
```

```
public void savePartNatureDon(){
    PartNatureDon partNatureDon = new PartNatureDon();
    Set<Don> dons = selected.getDons();

    List<NatureDon> natureDonList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Don don : dons){
        partNatureDon.setAssistance(don.getAssistance());
        
        List<NatureDon> natureDons = don.getNatureDonList();
        HashMap<String, Double> montant = new HashMap<>();
        for (NatureDon natureDon : natureDons){

            if (!natureDonList.stream().anyMatch(n->n.getLibelle().equals(natureDon.getLibelle()))) {
                natureDonList.add(natureDon);

                natureDonList.forEach (natureDon1 -> {
                        montant.putIfAbsent(natureDon1.getLibelle(), Double.valueOf(don.getMontantNatureDon().get(natureDon1.getLibelle())));
                        montant.computeIfPresent(natureDon1.getLibelle(), (n, nature) -> Double.valueOf(nature + don.getMontantNatureDon().get(natureDon1.getLibelle())));
                });
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you, please, specify what's wrong with the code you've posted? And it's also unclear how the image you've posted is related to the question, consider **replacing** it with an informative description. Also, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what the code is trying to accomplish. You have a set of `Don`s that you iterate to create a `PartnNatureDon`, but you overwrite the `assistance` with the last one you encounter. You seem to not be setting `natureDon` at all, and I don't know how you would without overwriting again. Now you're asking how to add up some contained amounts, but with the relations between the three types this unclear, I won't even make a guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
natureDonList.forEach (natureDon1 -> {
if(montant.containtsKey(natureDon1.getLibelle())){
   montant.put(natureDon1.getLibelle(), montant.get(natureDon1.getLibelle())+Double.valueOf(don.getMontantNatureDon().get(natureDon1.getLibelle())));
}else{
 montant.putIfAbsent(natureDon1.getLibelle(), Double.valueOf(don.getMontantNatureDon().get(natureDon1.getLibelle())));
}

            });
```